# Problemas para hacer diseño de una barra de búsqueda responsiva

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy incorporando una barra de búsqueda en la pagina principal de mi website de prueba, usando bootstrap 4. Esta barra de busqueda esta compuesta principalmente por un select (para seleccionar categoria), un input text para ingresar los titulos que se vayan a buscar, otro input text que es para buscar direcciones en un mapa (es el Geocoder de Mapbox API), dos campos de fecha (para hacer búsquedas por rango de fechas) y finalmente el botón de buscar.

Existen dos categorias:
1. Por Titulo
2. Por Fechas

Si selecciono por Titulo, Los campos de Fecha Desde y Hasta inicialmente estan ocultos, y el input text de titulos se muestra. Si selecciono Por Fechas, sucede todo lo contrario, aparecen los campos de fechas y se oculta el input text de títulos.

Inicialmente mi barra de busqueda ocupaba el 100% del ancho del dispositivo y todo iba bien, pero he tratado de reducirla a la mitad del ancho del contenedor, para que se vea más pequeña y sencilla, trate de reducir al maximo cada uno de los campos y que todo entrara y encajara bien en todos los tamaños de dispositivos (Moviles, Tablets, Pcs), pero lo que sucede es que en pantallas muy grandes se ve bien pero en dispositivos más pequeños no, los placeholders se cortan, el boton de buscar se vuelve más grande ya, la barra queda completamente descuadrada.

Este es el código actual:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select_categories_box").change(function(){
        if ($("#select_categories_box").val() == "por_fechas") {
        $("#inputSearchText").css("display", "none");
        $("#inputSearchDateFrom").css("display", "block");
        $("#inputSearchDateEnd").css("display", "block");
        }
        else{
        $("#inputSearchDateFrom").css("display", "none");
        $("#inputSearchDateEnd").css("display", "none");
        $("#inputSearchText").css("display", "block");
          }
        });
        });
```

```css
    .center-items{
        margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;  
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;

        background: rgb(0,0,0,0.2);
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        }

        .input_search_home_container
        {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 60% !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px !important;
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .input_search_home_container button, .input_search_home_container select
        {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: none;
        }

        .input_search_home_container input
        {
            margin-top: 0;
            -webkit-transition:none !important;
            -moz-transition:none !important;
            -o-transition:none !important;
            transition:none !important;
            width: 100%;
            height: 49px;
            border-radius: 0;
            border: none;
        }

        .input_search_home_container .form-control input:focus {
            color: #475F7B;
            border-color: #ffffff;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        .input_search_home_container .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
            background-color: #fff;
            border: none !important;
            border-radius: 0px !important; 
        }

        .select2-container--classic .select-lg, .select2-container--default .select-lg
        {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 0.7rem 0.7rem !important; 
        }

        .input_search_home_container button 
        {
        height: 50px;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        }

        .select2-container
        {
            min-height: 55px;
        } 

        .input_search_home_container .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 0rem;
        }

        .select2-container .selection{
          height: 100% !important;
        }
        .select2-container .select2-selection--single{
            height: 100% !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 567px) 
        {
        .input_search_home_container button
        {
            border-top-left-radius: 30px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
        }
        }

    .mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder {
        width: 100%;
        }

        .mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder, .mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder .suggestions {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            border-radius: 0px !important;
        }

        .mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--icon-search
        {
            left: 80% !important;
            width: 20px !important;
            height: 20px !important;
            top: 17px !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center-items">
    <div class="input_search_home_container animated slideInUp">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <select class="select2-size-lg form-control" id="select_categories_box">
    <option value="0">Categoria</option>
    <option value="por_titulo">Por Titulo</option>
    <option value="por_fechas">Por Fechas</option>
    </select>
    </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 p-0" style="height: 100%;" id="inputSearchText">
    <div class="form-group" style="height: 100%;"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searching_text_item" placeholder="Titulo del Articulo...">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0" style="height: 100%;" id="inputSearchDateFrom">
    <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left" style="height: 100%;">
    <input type="text" id="searching_enddate" class="form-control pickadate" placeholder="DESDE">
    <div class="form-control-position" style="right: 0 !important; height: 100%; ">
    <i class='bx bx-calendar'></i>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0" id="inputSearchDateEnd">
    <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left" style="height: 100%;">
    <input type="text" id="searching_fromdate" class="form-control pickadate" placeholder="HASTA">
    <div class="form-control-position" style="right: 0 !important; height: 100%;">
    <i class='bx bx-calendar'></i>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0" id="locationSearchSelect">
    <!-- AQUI INSERTO UN INPUT GEOCODER DINAMICAMENTE CUANDO SE CARGA LA API DE MAPBOX -->
    <input type="hidden" id="txtLongitudeLocation">
    <input type="hidden" id="txtLatitudeLocation">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-0">
    <button class="btn btn-warning glow" id="btn_search_items"><i class="bx bx-search"></i> Buscar</button>
    </div>              
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Lo que me gustaría saber es cómo puedo tener una barra de búsqueda al estilo de la barra de google por ejemplo, que no se distorsiona su diseño si se abre en dispositivos con resoluciones más pequeñas. Totalmente responsivo, que se adapte bien al tamaño del dispositivo sin que las letras o texto se corten, desaparezcan o se bajen a otra linea.

Trato que todos los campos de la barra de búsqueda se mantengan en una sola linea, inline-block, por lo menos en dispositivos de tamaño mediano y grande. En móviles no importa que los campos se coloquen con un display block ya que la pantalla por ser tan pequeña lo amerita.

Comment: Checa este sitio haber si te ayuda a resolver tu duda : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Comment: @Cesarin, ¿porqué piensas que la documentación de Bootstrap 3.4 sirve para resolver un problema de Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Es solo una referencia , de ahi puede partir para buscar algo que este relacionado con Bootstrap 4.

Comment: En el sitio oficial no encuentro mucha información al respecto: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/float/#responsive